# Correct way to resize swapChain in DirectX12

Tags: c++-winrt, directx-12

I am attempting to port the DirectX12/XAML UWP template over to a C++-WinRT version... where EVERYTHING is done via C++-WinRT and I can turn off CX. I'm currently stuck on how to *ResizeBuffers* on the *swapchain*. Before resizing the buffers I have to release all the buffer references. In C++/CX **ComPtr** there is **Reset()** method to release reference of the renderTarget buffers, but in C++/winrt **com_ptr** no such **Reset()** method exists and if I set *renderTarget* to *nullptr* in order to release it, it throws an exception shown in the Screenshot below. And if I don't set the *renderTarget* to *nullptr* then exception is not thrown but the swapChain is also not resized.

Later I also tried it using the wrl::ComPtr and the Reset() method it is still throwing the same error. Does anyone know the correct way of resizing the swapChain in DirectX12?

[Screenshot of the code and error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7SUc1.png)

Comment: Assigning a `nullptr` to a `com_ptr` is equivalent to calling `Reset` on WRL's `ComPtr`. Your issue is elsewhere.

Comment: Take a look at [this template](https://github.com/walbourn/directx-vs-templates/tree/main/d3d12game_uwp_cppwinrt_dr) for some ideas.

Answer (score 1):

You *can't* use a "fail-fast" error handler like [ThrowIfFailed](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/ThrowIfFailed) for `ResizeBuffers` or `Present`. Both return meaningful failure codes at runtime you must handle.

Specifically both can return `DXGI_ERROR_DEVICE_REMOVED` or `DXGI_ERROR_DEVICE_RESET` and you need to handle it. In fact, in the UWP environment, you will see this happen at start up so you must handle it--some 'classic' Win32 desktop apps just ignore it and crash at weird times like when Windows Update updates a driver while the game is running.

For details on handling 'lost-device' (which is really 'device removed'), see **DeviceResources** [.h](https://github.com/walbourn/directx-vs-templates/blob/main/d3d12game_uwp_cppwinrt_dr/DeviceResources.h) / [.cpp](https://github.com/walbourn/directx-vs-templates/blob/main/d3d12game_uwp_cppwinrt_dr/DeviceResources.cpp).

See also [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/gaming/handling-device-lost-scenarios) which is written for DirectX 11, but all the equivalent stuff has to happen for DirectX 12.

Comment: I checked for the device removed or reset issue but I don't think that's the issue in my case. On checking the output from DebugLayer it was throwing the following error: **D3D12 ERROR: ID3D12CommandAllocator::Reset: A command allocator 0x0000022B3BE50830:'Unnamed ID3D12CommandAllocator Object' is being reset before previous executions associated with the allocator have completed. [ EXECUTION ERROR #552: COMMAND_ALLOCATOR_SYNC]**. I am also flushing the GPU before resizing swapChain. Can you tell the reason behind the error?

Comment: You need to have more than one Command Allocator for a valid DirectX 12 swapchain, and you'll need to wait for the fence before doing the Reset. Again, see DeviceResources.